# Need to highlight value of html table on real time update table

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table1"></div>
```

**Script:**

```
var $table1 = $('.table1');
var prev;
$chatlog3.html(text); // text is html table getting from backend
var curr = $table1;


function compare(curr){
  if (!prev){
    prev = curr;
  }
  compareTables(curr, prev);
  prev = curr;  // updating previous table to current table after comparition
}
  function compareTables(curr, prev){
    var prevrows = prev.find('tbody > tr');
    curr.find('tbody > tr').each(function(index){
        var currrow = $(this);
        var prevrow = $(prevrows[index]);
        var prevtds = prevrow.find('td');
        // console.log('difference: table1:('+$(this).text()+')  table2:('+$(prevtds[index]).text()+')');
        currrow.find('td').each(function(index){
            if($(this).text().trim() != $(prevtds[index]).text().trim() ){
                $(this).css({'color':'#000000','background':'#f99479','font-weight':'700'});
                console.log('difference: table1:('+$(this).text()+')  table2:('+$(prevtds[index]).text()+')');

                //set row in error
                return;
            }
        });

    });
    }
```

In my code, previous and current table are always same. Why?

I want to update previous table with current table after comparing. In comparison, checking is there any values got update in current table with previous table.

If yes, then styling(highlighting those cells).

Comment: You only ever set `prev = curr` - nowhere do you set `prev` to anything else, so your previous and current tables are always the same.

Comment: Maybe you meant to `clone` the current table into `prev` so it can be compared?

Comment: @freedomn-m Yes, I want to clone current table into prev. Can you please help?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/clone/  Try `prev = curr.clone();`

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign a variable to a primitive type (string, number, boolean) then it copies that value to the new variable, eg:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a;
a = 2;
console.log(a,b) // == 2,1
```

but when you assign to an object, the new variable points to the same instance of the object, eg:

```
var a = new { value: 1 };
var b = a;
a.value = 2;
console.log(a.value,b.value) // == 2,2
```

this is the same with a jquery object

```
var curr = $('.table1');
var prev = curr;
```

`prev` now points to the same jquery object so any comparison will always be equal.

Instead, you need to `.clone()` the table *before* you make any changes, eg:

```
var curr = $('.table1');
var prev = curr.clone();  // now prev = a copy of the table, not the same instance
curr.find("tbody").append("<tr><td>new row</td></tr>");

console.log($("tr", curr).length == $("tr", prev).length) // false
```

Comment: Is there any jQuery plugin to do this task? by passing `table id`, it should do this job(like we see in the stock market tables).